# Splunk: Need help using transaction to get the pcode when this error occurs

Tags: splunk

I am trying to use the following search method to pull all events to include the actual pcode value here, in my example is 650404 where it says

> 2019-05-01 05:17:04,351 [http-bio-8081-exec-19] INFO 
>   {hostName=vmjsbatchprod01-s01}
>   EZTaxServiceImpl.processChargeTransaction:206 - pcode: 650404

when the following error occurs

> EZTaxServiceImpl.processChargeTransaction:253 - Error
>   billsoft.eztax.EZTaxException: PCode not found.

I've tried using the following search, but it fails to pull any results.

"EZTaxServiceImpl.processChargeTransaction:206" | transaction endswith="EZTaxServiceImpl.processChargeTransaction:253"

I wanted to see if I could successfully search for these events so I can use the event builder afterwards to pull my results into a report that goes to our billing team. They both have an output from the host vmjsbatchprod01-s01 and when I view the search results of one, I can easily scroll down and find the other output as well so I know for a fact I should be able to "join" these statements to get what I need.

This is the output I get when searching for just

> "EZTaxServiceImpl.processChargeTransaction:253"
>   Which outputs the error code only when bill tax fails to validate the pcode properly on a couple lines above it
>
> 2019-05-01 05:17:04,348 [http-bio-8081-exec-19] TRACE
>   {hostName=vmjsbatchprod01-s01} --------
>   EZTaxServiceImpl.processChargeTransaction:201 Enter --------
>   2019-05-01 05:17:04,349 [http-bio-8081-exec-19] INFO 
>   {hostName=vmjsbatchprod01-s01}
>   EZTaxServiceImpl.processChargeTransaction:202 - Transaction Type: 59
>   2019-05-01 05:17:04,349 [http-bio-8081-exec-19] INFO 
>   {hostName=vmjsbatchprod01-s01}
>   EZTaxServiceImpl.processChargeTransaction:203 - Service Type: 21
>   2019-05-01 05:17:04,350 [http-bio-8081-exec-19] INFO 
>   {hostName=vmjsbatchprod01-s01}
>   EZTaxServiceImpl.processChargeTransaction:204 - Amount: 0.0 2019-05-01
>   05:17:04,350 [http-bio-8081-exec-19] INFO 
>   {hostName=vmjsbatchprod01-s01}
>   EZTaxServiceImpl.processChargeTransaction:205 - Number of Lines: 3
>   2019-05-01 05:17:04,351 [http-bio-8081-exec-19] INFO 
>   {hostName=vmjsbatchprod01-s01}
>   EZTaxServiceImpl.processChargeTransaction:206 - pcode: 650404
>   2019-05-01 05:17:04,351 [http-bio-8081-exec-19] INFO 
>   {hostName=vmjsbatchprod01-s01}
>   EZTaxServiceImpl.processChargeTransaction:207 - event id: null
>   2019-05-01 05:17:04,352 [http-bio-8081-exec-19] ERROR
>   {hostName=vmjsbatchprod01-s01}
>   EZTaxServiceImpl.processChargeTransaction:253 - Error
>   billsoft.eztax.EZTaxException: PCode not found.   at
>   billsoft.eztax.Util.throwEZTaxException(Util.java:313)
>   ~[eztax-9.20.1905-1.jar:?]    at
>   billsoft.eztax.Transaction.calculateTaxes(Native Method)
>   ~[eztax-9.20.1905-1.jar:?]    at
>   billsoft.eztax.Transaction.calculateTaxes(Transaction.java:1231)
>   ~[eztax-9.20.1905-1.jar:?]    at
>   com.nextiva.billsoft.service.EZTaxServiceImpl.processChargeTransaction(EZTaxServiceImpl.java:236)
>   [nextiva-eztax-service-1.0.70.jar:?]  at
>   com.nextiva.billsoft.controller.EZTaxController.processChargeTransaction(EZTaxController.java:128)
>   [EZTaxController.class:?]     at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor107.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_171]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_171]    at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>   [spring-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
>   [spring-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
>   [servlet-api.jar:?]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>   [servlet-api.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.88]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.88]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.88]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.88]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.88]     at
>   com.nextiva.utilities.rest.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilter(RequestContextFilter.java:60)
>   [nextivaUtilities-6.0.9.jar:?]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.88]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.88]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.88]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.88]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.88]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.88]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.88]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.88]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.88]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.88]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.88]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1139)
>   [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.88]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
>   [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.88]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
>   [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.88]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [?:1.8.0_171]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [?:1.8.0_171]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.88]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   [?:1.8.0_171]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured this out and figured out I needed to use a unique "startswith=" constraint and also define the sourcetype="directory" | before the rest of my search.